# laravel ORM merge two json arrays

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, merge

Excuse me, I use laravel ORM have two json arrays , like this:

php

```
$personnels = Personnel::all();
$skills = Languagelv::all();
return view('bs_sidebar/recommend',[
            'personnels' => $personnels,
            'skills' => $skills,
]);
```

model

```
class Personnel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'personnels';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'sex'];
}

class Personnels_skill extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'personnels_skill';
    protected $fillable = ['skill_name','personnels_id'];
}
```

json result

```
{personnels:[
    {"id" : 1,"name"  : "bruce","sex"   : 1},
    {"id" : 2,"name" : "peter","sex"  : 0}
    ]
};
{skill:[
        {"id" : 1,"skill_name": 'php', "personnels_id" : 1},
        {"id" : 2,"skill_name": 'jsp',"personnels_id" : 1},
        {"id" : 3,"skill_name": 'asp',"personnels_id" : 2}
       ]
};
```

I want to merge two json arrays

(personnels id = skill personnels_id )

skill arrays is into personnels arrays

like this result:

```
{merge:[
        {"id":1,"name":"bruce","sex:1,"skill":[{"id": 1,"skill_name": 'php', "personnels_id" : 1},{"id": 2,"skill_name": 'jsp',"personnels_id" : 1}]},

        {"id":2,"name":"peter","sex":0,"skill":[{"id": 3,"skill_name": 'asp',"personnels_id" : 2}
        ]
};
```

How can I do , please help me, thank you.

Comment: show your code then i can help you

Comment: @lakhvirkumar ok! thank you~!  Has been showing php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's try this 
it will work.

```
      foreach ($personnels as $key => $value) {
        $skill_list = DB::table('skill')->where('personnels_id','=',$value->id)->get();
        $personnels[$key]->skill = $skill_list;   
                    }  

return view('bs_sidebar/recommend',['personnels' => $personnels]);
```

Comment: thank you replay , i try this it, but is error  [Creating default object from empty value]   in  $personnels[$key]->skill = $skill_list;

Comment: sorry!  ok  ,  i'll try this code , but is get error message [Creating default object from empty value]   error is in the $personnels[$key]->skill = $skill_list;

Comment: i try delete 「->skill」, is error disappear ,but don't get any message

Comment: please use this , line no 2 $value['id'] instead of $value->id

Comment: can you please print the $value['id'] inside of foreach ,if it is value coming or not

Comment: oh sorry! is my miss  , There is a numerical value, thank you! I'll check it

Comment: This is going to run `n + 1` queries and could be accomplished with 2 queries.

Comment: @fubar thanks~!  how to accomplished with 2 queries?

Answer (score 3):

If you have your relationships correctly configured in your models, you should be able to do the following:

```
$personnel = Personnel::with('skills')->get();
return view('bs_sidebar/recommend', compact('personnel'));
```

**Edit**
Given your models, if you add the following relationships you will be able to use the Eloquent query above.

```
class Personnel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'personnels';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 
        'sex',
    ];

    public function skills() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Personnels_skill::class, 'personnel_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Personnels_skill extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'personnels_skill';

    protected $fillable = [
        'personnel_id',
        'skill_name',
    ];

    public $timestamps = false; 

    public function personnel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Personnel::class, 'id', 'personnel_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: thank your reply!  but I don't know , how can configured models.. i'm try this

Comment: @Bruce - update your question with your database schema and model code.

Comment: @Bruce - your database schema was relevant to know what your foreign keys were. As it happens, you've included them in your models `$fillable` array, so no matter.

Comment: this is  Good practice